# I would like to open a qlik file with no data and save it in another location all using a bat file

Tags: batch-file, qlikview

I have the command to open a qlik file with no data , but i would like to make a bat out of it with the option to save it in another location ( with the help of a .bat file)

so the bat file should start with 
run C:\Program Files\QlikView\qv.exe /nodata \qlik\qlikdocument.qvw

then i would need to do something like Save as qlikdocument_ddmmyyyy.qvw in another location, let`s say :  \qlik\backup  .

Any ideas? is it possible?

Thanks,
Cezar

Comment: why not just use: [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) "\qlik\qlikdocument.qvw" "\qlik\backup\qlikdocument_ddmmyyyy.qvw"

Comment: most files are reloaded and to store less space i need to empty them first ,  will copy work as a save as after they are emptied ?

Comment: Are you willing to make modification to the QVW for this to work? Since there is no out of the box solution for this.

Comment: what modification to be exact ? besides to load it empty i presume ?! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I know of, is the following.

In your QVW, add the following if statement around your entire script.

```
IF (not IsPartialReload()) THEN
//SCRIPT
ENDIF
```

Then from commandline. reload it with the following:

```
qv.exe qlikdocument.qvw /nodata /rp
copy C:\qlikdocument.qvw C:\qlikdocument_ddmmyyyy.qvw
```

Comment: This would be the easiest. The other solutions I can think of will require VB code to be implemented into the QVW.